Why my USB microphone isn't detected by the Realtek Audio Console?
I don't know why my USB microphone isn't detected by the Realtek Audio Console.




(...) why my USB microphone isn't detected in Realtek Audio Console
(...)

Because your USB microphone is an independent audio device like all other USB audio devices and also HDMI/DP audio.
Realtek software is intended to manage the onboard Realtek sound chip and the ports it controls only, not any other sound card/chip.
